# How to tell tensorflow that inputs are logically grouped with each other

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

For example I have a 5v5 game where each player is represented by 10 floats and I want to tell tensorflow that each 10 floats is related to a player and each 50 floats is related to a team. Is there some way to group values together within a single tensor or should I just let the AI figure it out?

A simplified example - instead of passing:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
c    a    t    h    a    t
```

I want to tell tensorflow that each 3 elements is logically related to each other so that the AI can better understand the model:

```
col1     col2
[c,a,t]  [h,a,t]
```

Currently I read my dataset in like this:

```
field_names = ["elo", "map", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "result"]
df_train = pd.read_csv('input/match_results.csv', names=field_names, skiprows=1, usecols=range(2, 13))


for count in range(1, 6):
    str_count = str(count)
    df_train['c' + str_count] = df_train['c' + str_count].map(champ_dict)
    df_train['e' + str_count] = df_train['e' + str_count].map(champ_dict)
target = df_train.pop('result')
targets = np.array(list(x for x in target.values))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_train.values, targets))
```

But now each column c1-c5 and e1-e5 will be 10 floats instead of 1 float each. Each group of 10 floats represents a player so I'd like them to be logically grouped.

Further each group of 50 floats will represent a team so I'd like to logically group them too (and let tensorflow know that order doesn't matter for the teams or players).

Comment: Would I use tf.concat to group inputs together? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct, but this is what I have now...it converts my numbers into an array of numbers using champ_features_dict

```
  def converter(x):
        if isinstance(x, str):
            return pd.Series(champ_features_dict[x])
        else:
            return x

    df_train["c" + str_count] = df_train["c" + str_count].apply(converter)
```